# Data not being copied in new div created only name getting copied

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

My Query:

When I click on the Add button then a new div row is added without any data. in place of it, the variable names get added. i.e. `Image productTitle  productPrice.`

`(productTitle,productImage,productPrice)` when printed on console or alerted  the values are produced correctly. `(Product 1 ,"url",100 )`

but does not get copied on calling `addtocart` function through arguments and gives output as variable names >> `(productTitle, productImage, productPrice)` not the values

Please help

```js
    //Java Script code 
    var addbtn =document.getElementsByClassName('addbtn');

    for(var i=0 ;i<addbtn.length;i++)
    {

        addbtn[i].addEventListener('click',function(e)
        {

          currentbtn = e.target;
          productcontainer = currentbtn.parentElement;
           productTitle = productcontainer.getElementsByClassName('product-title')[0].innerText;
           productImage= productcontainer.getElementsByClassName('product-img')[0].src;
           productPrice= productcontainer.getElementsByClassName('product-price')[0].innerText;
          // addnew( productTitle, productPrice,productImage);
          
          
      

            addtocart(productTitle,productImage,productPrice);
        });


    }
    cartContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cartContainer')[0];
    function addtocart(productTitle,productImage,productPrice)
    {

    newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.classList.add('row');
    insideContent ='<div class="col-sm cartImage"><img src="productImage"></div><div class ="col-sm card cartTitle">productTitle</div><div class="col-sm cartPrice">productPrice</div><div class="col-sm removeBotton" >Remove </div>';
    newdiv.innerHTML =  insideContent;
    cartContainer.appendChild(newdiv);








    }
```

````html
 
//HTML code

    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cart.css">
    
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
       <section>
    
    <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3  row-cols-sm-2">
      <div class="col mb-4">
        <div class="card h-80">
            
    
          <div class="card-body  d-flex flex-column align-items-center img-fluid">
                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81bDJ8AC5HL._AC_SX180_SY120_QL70_.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid product-img" alt="..."id="cardimg">
            <h5 class="card-title product-title">Product1</h5>
            <p class="card-text product-price">100</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning addbtn">Add</button>
    
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
          <div class="col mb-4">
        <div class="card h-80">
       
          <div class="card-body  d-flex flex-column align-items-center ">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61utX8kBDlL._AC_UL320_.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid product-img" alt="..."id="cardimg">
            <h5 class="card-title product-title">Product2</h5>
            <p class="card-text product-price">200</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning addbtn">Add</button>
    
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
          <div class="col mb-4">
        <div class="card h-80">
    
          <div class="card-body  d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71JhEnGtlfL._AC_UL320_.jpg"class="card-img-top img-fluid product-img" alt="..."id="cardimg">
            <h5 class="card-title product-title">Product3</h5>
            <p class="card-text product-price">300</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning addbtn">Add</button>
    
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        
         
        </div>
           
           
           </section>
          
     <div class="cartContainer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm ">
          Product
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          Title
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
         Price
        </div>
             <div class="col-sm">
          Action
        </div>
      </div>
      

      <!--This new div row content  will be added in new div-->
      <!--<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm cartImage">
         <img src=" https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81bDJ8AC5HL._AC_SX180_SY120_QL70_.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm card cartTitle">
        Product1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm cartPrice">
         100
        </div>
             <div class="col-sm removeBotton" >
          Remove
        </div>
      </div>-->
  
    
    
    </div>
    <script src="cart.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

```

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fully working solution for you with `add` to cart and `remove` from cart functionality.

I have also simplified your `code` by using latest methods like `forEach` and `querySelectorAll` to get all `Add` - Using getElementByClassName is not feasible here at all - its very old method and is not being alot.

Firstly we need to get add the buttons using `querySelectorAll` and then use `forEach` loop to create an eventListener on all of them.

When we click on `add` we will pass the `data` to our `addtocart` and then use `concatenation` + to show the price, image, title in the cart.

Secondly, we can use `previousElementSibling` function to get the previous element of the `currentTarget` this will ensure we get the right data each time we on a specific `add` button.

Lastly, I have also added a `remove` button each product you add to `cart` - which will allow you remove that item we appended from the cart container using onClick function.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
//Java Script code 
var addbtn = document.querySelectorAll('.addbtn');
var cartContainer = document.querySelector('.cartContainer')

//get all add buttons
addbtn.forEach(function(add) {
  add.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var currentbtn = e.target;
    var productcontainer = currentbtn.parentElement;
    var productTitle = currentbtn.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerText;
    var productImage = currentbtn.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.src;
    var productPrice = currentbtn.previousElementSibling.innerText
    addtocart(productTitle, productImage, productPrice);
  });
})

//Add to cart
function addtocart(productTitle, productImage, productPrice) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.classList.add('row');
  var insideContent = '<div class="cart_item"><div class="col-sm cartImage"><img src="' + productImage + '"></div><div class ="col-sm card cartTitle">' + productTitle + '</div><div class="col-sm cartPrice">' + productPrice + '</div><button class="btn-sm btn-warning removeBotton" onclick="removeItem(this)">Remove</button></div>';
  newdiv.innerHTML = insideContent;
  cartContainer.appendChild(newdiv);
}

//Remove from cart
function removeItem(e) {
  e.parentElement.remove() //remove from cart
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cart.css">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>

    <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3  row-cols-sm-2">
      <div class="col mb-4">
        <div class="card h-80">


          <div class="card-body  d-flex flex-column align-items-center img-fluid">
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81bDJ8AC5HL._AC_SX180_SY120_QL70_.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid product-img" alt="..." id="cardimg">
            <h5 class="card-title product-title">Product1</h5>
            <p class="card-text product-price">100</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning addbtn">Add</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col mb-4">
        <div class="card h-80">

          <div class="card-body  d-flex flex-column align-items-center ">
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61utX8kBDlL._AC_UL320_.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid product-img" alt="..." id="cardimg">
            <h5 class="card-title product-title">Product2</h5>
            <p class="card-text product-price">200</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning addbtn">Add</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mb-4">
        <div class="card h-80">

          <div class="card-body  d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71JhEnGtlfL._AC_UL320_.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid product-img" alt="..." id="cardimg">
            <h5 class="card-title product-title">Product3</h5>
            <p class="card-text product-price">300</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning addbtn">Add</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>


  </section>

  <div class="cartContainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm ">
        Product
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        Title
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        Price
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        Action
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--This new div row content  will be added in new div-->
    <!--<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm cartImage">
         <img src=" https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81bDJ8AC5HL._AC_SX180_SY120_QL70_.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm card cartTitle">
        Product1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm cartPrice">
         100
        </div>
             <div class="col-sm removeBotton" >
          Remove
        </div>
      </div>-->



  </div>
  <script src="cart.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you help me with the query that ,I dont want to add multiple items of same type in the container only 1 allowed  of same type ,if we try to put more than 1 of same type then  the editor displays alert messsge item already added.

Comment: @ayush yeah sure. I have created a working JS fiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/sa4kwt78/ - you will not able to product more then once. If you remove the same product then you can add it again else you will not be able to. I have saving the product name in an array and checked it the product name exist already or not.

Answer (score 1):

In the row beginning `insideContent =`, your variable names are inside the text string denoted with single quotes at start and end (`'`).

You need to change this line so that the variable names are outside the text string.

This can be done by concatenating them.

For example:

```
insideContent = 'text string' + variableName + 'text string' + variableName
```

Applying this to the above use case, you can simply replace that line in your existing code with the following:

```
insideContent ='<div class="col-sm cartImage"><img src="' + productImage + '"></div><div class ="col-sm card cartTitle">' + productTitle + '</div><div class="col-sm cartPrice">' + productPrice + '</div><div class="col-sm removeBotton" >Remove </div>';
```

Comment: Thank you ,for your answer ,I also heard about>>insideDiv = `<div class="col-sm cartImage"> <img src="${_productImage}"></div>
<div class="col-sm cartTitle"> ${_productTitle} </div>
<div class="col-sm cartPrice"> ${_productPrice}</div>
 <div class="col-sm removeButton"> Remove</div>`;    dollar sign used in jquery .to do this ,can you explain this If you have some info about this ??

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer jQuery? It's an extra dependency. This should be achievable simply by using the concatenation. Did you try my solution above? If so, did it work? If it did, you could mark it correct and open another question about a jQuery alternative. If it didn't work, let us know and we will troubleshoot/adjust. If you want a jQuery-only solution, please amend the question to say so.

Answer (score 0):

concatenate productImage

```
insideContent ='<div class="col-sm cartImage"><img src="'+productImage+'"></div><div class ="col-sm card cartTitle">productTitle</div><div class="col-sm cartPrice">productPrice</div><div class="col-sm removeBotton" >Remove </div>';
```

Comment: Thank you ,for your answer ,I also heard about>>insideDiv = <div class="col-sm cartImage"> <img src="${_productImage}"></div> <div class="col-sm cartTitle"> ${_productTitle} </div> <div class="col-sm cartPrice"> ${_productPrice}</div>  <div class="col-sm removeButton"> Remove</div>; dollar sign used in jquery .to do this ,can you explain this If you have some info about this